# What's the problem of my prime test code?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

I implemented the [Miller-Rabin prime test algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Algorithm_and_running_time) found on wikipedia with Python 3.

It seems to be working correctly with most numbers but occasionaly fail on certain numbers.

For example, the prime number 99999999999999997 is judged to be NOT prime.

I implemented the algorithm line by line and I have no clue where the problem is.
Can any one help me ?

Here is my code.

the test input is:

1

99999999999999997

(No empty line between two lines.)

And the expected output should be YES, but it gives NO on my machine.

```
import random

def isPrime(n, k = 5):
'''
Primality test using Miller-Rabin method.
n The number to test primality.
k The number of M-R test to perform.
'''
if n == 1:
    return False
if n == 2 or n == 3:
    return True
if n % 2 == 0:
    return False

# Calculate d
nn = n - 1
s = 1
while nn % (2 ** s) == 0:
    s += 1
s -= 1
d = int(nn / (2 ** s))

for i in range(k):
    a = random.randint(2, n - 1)
    x = pow(a,d,n)
    if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
        continue
    flag = True
    for r in range(1, s):
        x = pow(x,2,n)
        if x == 1:
            return False
        if x == n - 1:
            flag = False
            break
    if not flag:
        continue
    return False
return True

count = int(input())
for i in range(count):
    if isPrime(int(input())):
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

Comment: I just tried running the code you posted, and your example worked for me.  Maybe you typed it in wrong (ie forgot a 9 somewhere?)

Comment: see my edited post. I have solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an implementation of Miller-Rabin I wrote a while ago. It has never given me an unexpected result -- though that doesn't mean it won't! It is substantially identical to the one you pasted, and it declares 99999999999999997 to be prime. Yours did too, when I tested it -- so that's a second to [Mikola's opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481727/whats-the-problem-of-my-prime-test-code/6481834#6481834). **But see below for one possible problem that I can't easily test... scratch that, I tested it, and it was the problem**.

When it comes to primality testing, I'm no expert, but I spent a lot of time thinking about and coming to understand Miller-Rabin, and I'm pretty sure your implementation is spot-on.

```
def is_prime_candidate(self, p, iterations=7):  
    if p == 1 or p % 2 == 0: return False       
    elif p < 1: raise ValueError("is_prime_candidate: n must be a positive integer")
    elif p < self.maxsmallprime: return p in self.smallprimes

    odd = p - 1
    count = 0
    while odd % 2 == 0:
        odd //= 2
        count += 1

    for i in range(iterations):
        r = random.randrange(2, p - 2) 
        test = pow(r, odd, p)
        if test == 1 or test == p - 1: continue
        for j in range(count - 1):
            test = pow(test, 2, p)
            if test == 1: return False
            if test == p - 1: break
        else: return False
        print i
    return True
```

The one thing I noticed about your code that seemed off was this:

```
d = int(nn / (2 ** s))
```

Why `int`, I thought to myself. Then I realized you must be using Python 3. So that means you're doing *floating point* arithmetic here and then converting to int. That seemed iffy. So I tested it on ideone. [And lo!](http://ideone.com/SQeZx) the result was `False`. So I changed the code to use explicit floor division (`d = nn // (2 ** s)`). [And lo!](http://ideone.com/4M0tk) it was `True`.

Comment: You're correct ! But isn't it strange that Mikola didn't encouter this problem with the same code ? Is it because they're using Python 2 ? PS. Why is floor division neede here ? It seems a simple division problem.

Comment: @Spirit Zhang, look at the operation: `99999999999999996 // 4`. The result is `24999999999999999`. Now look at `float(24999999999999999)`. Result: `25000000000000000.0`. Floats have limited precision, and in this case, the value gets rounded up as a result.

Comment: P.S. yes, Mikola must have used Python 2 to test the code, as I did the first time around.

Comment: @Spirit Zhang, btw, [here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4600/lectures/comp4600_primality.pdf) is a great article on primality testing algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to reiterate my comment, since my testing seems to indicate your example is working.  I strongly suspect that you just mistyped your test case.  Maybe you can try taking a second look at it?  Here is what I got from running it:

> In [12]: millerrabin.isPrime(99999999999999997, 5)
>
> Out[12]: True

EDIT:  I just ran the updated version, and here is the output from the console:

```
1
99999999999999997
YES
```

Again, this looks correct.

Comment: +1 -- I tested it and got the same result. Also, the algorithm looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the Miller-Rabin algorithm is only probabilistic. Were you not aware of this, or are you using a modified, non probabilistic version?

Comment: The test can mistale a composite for a prime, not the other way around.

Comment: I know it's a probabilistic one, but it should return the right answer provided you run it enough times. But the problem with my code is that however times you run it, it gives wrong answer on certain input.